# Google Script Time-Based Trigger -> Asking for Authorization all the time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

So I have this google script function that reads information from a google spreadsheet and sends an email with the data. I set up a time-based trigger that activates every day at a certain hour but the problem is that every time it triggers the script ask for authorization so basically what I'm receiving is the email with this "time-based" error that asks for authorization.

The function self-works perfectly when I manually execute it and confirm the authorization myself.

I set up the time-based trigger via code and the trigger option of the scripts but none of them seems to work.

Do you guys know a way to always keep the authorization on so the trigger can work and send the email with the data?

Comment: where is the function?

Comment: Hi Ricks! Please add some more details, i.e. code, to show what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

so to add some additional information here, this is the code I'm using right now:

The spreadsheet is shared between two people, me and a co-worker.

If I manually execute this script, it will ask for authorization and then send to my email the data I need. My problem comes when I tried to set up a trigger to automatically execute this script. Every time the trigger execute the script I get an email saying that it needs authorization.

Function: emailCarts
Error Message: Authorization is required to perform this action.                       Activation: Time-Based

```
function emailCharts(sheet,emails,emailSubject){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Graficos"); 
var emailSubject = 'Reporte Automático Reclamos y Sugerencias ' + Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yy");
var emails = 'MY_EMAIL'; // your email ID
var charts = sheet.getCharts();

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("Tabla");
var schedRange = sheet2.getDataRange();

var body = '<div style="text-align:left;display: inline-block;font-family: 
arial,sans,sans-serif">'
body += '<H1>'+ 'Reclamos Abiertos ' +'</H1>';
body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
body += '</div><br>';
debugger;  


if(charts.length==0){

  MailApp.sendEmail({to: emails,subject: "ERROR:"+emailSubject,htmlBody: "No hay 
 gráficos en el spreadsheet"});    
  return;

}

var chartBlobs = new Array(charts.length); 
var emailBody = "Estimados,<br><br> Junto con saludar, se hace envío del reporte 
automático de los Reclamos/Sugerencias/Felicitaciones Abiertos y Cerrados, 
correspondiente a la fecha: "
            + Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yy"); 

var emailImages = {};


for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){

  var builder = charts[i].modify();
  builder.setOption('vAxis.format', '#');
  var newchart = builder.build();
  chartBlobs[i] = newchart.getAs('image/png');
  emailBody = emailBody + "<p align='center'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'></p>";
  emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];

}

  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to: emails[i], subject: emailSubject, htmlBody: emailBody+body, inlineImages: emailImages});
 }

}



function getHtmlTable(range){
  var ss = range.getSheet().getParent();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  startRow = range.getRow();
  startCol = range.getColumn();
  lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  lastCol = range.getLastColumn();

  // Read table contents
  var data = range.getValues();

  // Get css style attributes from range
  var fontColors = range.getFontColors();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var fontFamilies = range.getFontFamilies();
  var fontSizes = range.getFontSizes();
  var fontLines = range.getFontLines();
  var fontWeights = range.getFontWeights();
  var horizontalAlignments = range.getHorizontalAlignments();
  var verticalAlignments = range.getVerticalAlignments();

  // Get column widths in pixels
  var colWidths = [];
  for (var col=startCol; col<=lastCol; col++) { 
    colWidths.push(sheet.getColumnWidth(col));
  }
  // Get Row heights in pixels
  var rowHeights = [];
  for (var row=startRow; row<=lastRow; row++) { 
    rowHeights.push(sheet.getRowHeight(row));
  }

  // Future consideration...
  var numberFormats = range.getNumberFormats();

  // Build HTML Table, with inline styling for each cell
  var tableFormat = 'style="border:1.5px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text- align:center" border = 1.5 cellpadding = 5';
  var html = ['<table '+tableFormat+'>'];
  // Column widths appear outside of table rows
  for (col=0;col<colWidths.length;col++) {
    html.push('<col width="'+colWidths[col]+'">')
  }
  // Populate rows
  for (row=0;row<data.length;row++) {
    html.push('<tr height="'+rowHeights[row]+'">');
    for (col=0;col<data[row].length;col++) {
      // Get formatted data
      var cellText = data[row][col];
      if (cellText instanceof Date) {
        cellText = Utilities.formatDate(
                     cellText,
                     ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                     "dd/MM/yy");
      }
      var style = 'style="'
                + 'color: ' + fontColors[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-family: ' + fontFamilies[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-size: ' + fontSizes[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-weight: ' + fontWeights[row][col]+'; '
                + 'background-color: ' + backgrounds[row][col]+'; '
                + 'text-align: ' + horizontalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                + 'vertical-align: ' + verticalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                +'"';
      html.push('<td ' + style + '>'
                +cellText
                +'</td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
  }
  html.push('</table>');

  return html.join('');
 }
```